# python - regex: we are looking for the input of a function

Tags: python, regex, function, syntax

```
import re

def step_through_with(s):
    pattern = re.compile(s + ',')
    if pattern == True:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The task is to find a word in a sentence, which is the input parameter of the function. How should the syntax look like?

Comment: `pattern == True`?

Comment: Do you want to ask how will the parameter be passed to the function? Or you want to know how the re module can be used to do the matching?

Comment: What kind of a word are you searching for? Please provide comprehensive examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a word in a sentence, you have to take into account boundaries (so searching for 'fun' won't match 'function' for instance).

An example:

```
import re

def step_through_with(sentence, word):
    pattern = r'\b{}\b'.format(word)
    if re.search(pattern, sentence):
        return True
    return False


sentence = 'we are looking for the input of a function'

print step_through_with(sentence, 'input')   # True
print step_through_with(sentence, 'fun')     # False
```